# Object of a sentence ambiguity

Tags: relative-clauses, ambiguity

The sentence: 守りたいのはあなた

This sentence can either mean "The one I want to protect is you" or it can mean "the one who wants to protect (someone else) is you". Any way to distinguish besides context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This sentence can either mean "The one I want to protect is you" or it can mean "the one who wants to protect (someone else) is you".

Yes, it can mean both.

> Any way to distinguish besides context?

No, there is no way to distinguish besides context. But when you write a sentence like this, you can simply add a が-/を-phrase to disambiguate. When a が-marked phrase is already present before のは, あなた will be automatically interpreted as the object.

- **僕が**守りたいのはあなた。
  It's you who I want to protect.
- **彼を**守りたいのはあなた。
  It's you who wants to protect him.

---

Your sentence is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010), but 守りたいあなた is already ambiguous. There are many similar questions:

- [Clarification about how 惚れた should be translated](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60895/5010)
- [Relative Clause Ambiguous](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60385/5010)
- [The meaning of ”あれは魔術師に与えられた祝福”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76392/5010)
- [が in subordinate clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30171/5010)

For example 惚れたのは君だ means both "It's you who fell in love [to me]" and "It's you who [I] fell in love to". 好きなのは彼女だ means both "*She* loves [him]" and "[He] loves *her*".

Comment: +1, but I think it also might not hurt to read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25667/what-exactly-is-the-subject/25668#25668), so he/she could get clear on the subject/object distinction.